# Losing Experience In Killing Floor

Tags: killing-floor

I just started playing Killing Floor on my Desktop, then I moved over to playing it on my laptop.  I was pretty happy to see that my progress was transfered over automatically to my laptop when I installed it via Steam.

The problem is that it doesn't seem like I'm ever gaining any experience.  For example in one game I was playing online and gained level 3 Medic.  At the end of the game, I left the server and joined a new one to find I was only level 2 Medic.

I noticed the same thing happening when I was playing a Solo game.  What's going on here?

Edit:  So far I've tried:

- Verifying the game cache files in Steam.
- When that didn't work, I tried reinstalling the game.
- There are no mutators on, and I'm playing on KF-Manor, KF-WestLondon, KF-Farm
- I've tried multiple servers online, and solo games.
- The Desktop was running Windows, my laptop is running OSX.

Edit 2: I just noticed that at the end of one solo game my stats have improved, but by the time the next map loads they have reset.  This is the same for multiplayer games.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer then loading the game again?  Also, make sure there are no mutators on as those negate experience gain.

Comment: @hammythepig, Yessir, updated the question with steps I've tried.

Comment: kk thanks! hmmm, have you tried playing again on your desktop? see if it still tracks exp there or not

Comment: @hammythepig can't test it on my desktop now, I'm in currently in a different country than my desktop. :/

Comment: alright, well I know that this is a common problem, I've heard about it a lot and it even happened to me a couple times before.  I got into the habit of not leaving a server until the next map was loaded and it seemed to have saved all my experience then.  other than that I don't have a sure answer :/

Comment: Is that the same for playing solo games, too?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never play solo games.  But I would wait just the same, just in case

Comment: I'm having nearly exactly the same problem, and near as I can figure, some servers will track and some won't. I've heard things like 1/100 times, it'll track progress. Still looking for a fix.

Comment: @user43496 Yeah, I stopped playing Killing Floor on my Mac.  They fixed it shortly after I posted this, but it was broken again by the next update.  It looks like their QA department just doesn't care for OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty clear on the TripWire forums that this problem is related to it being on Mac.  And from looking there and reading what others have to say, the problem has existed for years now.

It's probably pretty safe to assume that TripWire has no intention of fixing this given their track record.  I guess the work-around is to use Windows or to buy games from legitimate companies. :(

Answer (score 0):

Old post but since the problem still exists I will post the solution that worked for me.

I'm running KF via steam on Ubuntu 14.04 and after some games my XP started reseting.

I tried a clean install, verify game cache, etc. Nothing worked.

Ends up that in Mac and Linux when you join a server that has mutators (addons) they are downloaded in the wrong location, than a security error occurs and you gained XP is lost after you leave the game.

I found a script that fixed the problem, it basically moves the mutator files to the right folders. Unfortunately you need to run it after downloading NEW mutators.

The script can be found here :https://gist.github.com/rafaelrpinto/1d610ede0e3b8b46e6c8c7a77def8a97

```
#!/bin/bash

# Folder where the incorrect downloaded mutators are
CACHE_FOLDER=~/.killingfloor/Cache
# Folder where they should be after renamed
STEAM_SYSTEM_FOLDER=~/.steam/steamapps/common/KillingFloor/System


cd $CACHE_FOLDER

while read p; do
  # For each non-empty entry of cache.ini
  if [ -n "$p" ]
    then
        IFS='=' read -r -a array <<< "$p"
        echo "${array[0]}.uxx"
        echo "${array[1]}"
        # Move the file to the steam folder with the correct name
        mv $CACHE_FOLDER/"${array[0]}.uxx" $STEAM_SYSTEM_FOLDER/${array[1]}
  fi
done < cache.ini

# Erase the previous values from the cache.ini file
echo "[Cache]" > cache.ini
```

Comment: The script is you link to is either removed or hidden.

Comment: The original script was removed apparently. You can find it on this url https://gist.github.com/rafaelrpinto/1d610ede0e3b8b46e6c8c7a77def8a97